# How to stop an integer from reseting to original value with each run?

Tags: java, selenium

I've written an automated selenium jar that will change my Discord avatar (https://discordapp.com/). I have a folder where all images are stored that are called by Selenium to be uploaded. I've also written an automater that will change the names of the images so the next one will be uploaded when the jar is launched.

I want to make the process easier by declaring an integer that will increase with each run, which will be then turned to a string to the corresponding image name (i.e. "avatar_1", "avatar_2", "avatar_3").

But every time I run it, the integer resets to the original value. Is there a way for the jar to remember the previous value of the integer with every run?

Here is what I came up with:

```
static WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
static WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
public static int i = 0;

public static void main (String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    changeAvatar();
}

public static void changeAvatar() throws InterruptedException {

    driver.navigate().to("https://discordapp.com/");

    changeAvatarSteps.loginScreen();
    changeAvatarSteps.enterInformation();
    changeAvatarSteps.loginToAccount();
    changeAvatarSteps.userSettings();
    changeAvatarSteps.editAccount();
    changeAvatarSteps.changeAvatar(); //pathToAvatar+Integer.toString(i);

    driver.quit();

    i++;

}
```

Comment: You'll need to write the integer to a file or a database to store it across different executions of your program.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Hmm I've never heard of writing items into a file and using them. Do you know by any chance know any place I can read about it? Just in case... I'm using IntelliJ.

Comment: Just read about reading and writing files in Java. Probably thousands of good google results.

Comment: Just have your script pick a new avatar at random (excluding your current avatar). No need to write anything to disk, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword `static` only makes it so the variable does not reset every time you create a new object with that variable as a parameter. Here you are not dealing with objects, so `static` would not help you.

The way to solve this problem would be, as @Matt said, to store the integer value in a separate file and increment it as necessary across different executions of your program. Some classes to look into for file input/output functions are `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream`. A great resource for those classes is below.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_files_io.htm

Hope this helped!

Comment: I've read more into how I/O works, but I couldn't really figure out how to implement it correctly. Eventually I decided to create an array of all of the files in the folder, and then make a randomizer randomly pick it.  `static String path = "myPath";`  `static File[] avatarFiles = new File(path).listFiles();`
`static File avatarNames = avatarFiles[rand.nextInt(avatarFiles.length)];`
`static String actualNames = avatarNames.toString();`